# Obtaining a Micronaut HttpClient with url from property

Tags: java, micronaut

I want to [obtain](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/httpClient.html#_obtaining_a_httpclient) the HttpClient by the Client annotation, so it is managed by Micronaut. However this way I can't use a url from my property file:

```
public FooService(
   @Value("${url}") String url,
   // I can't use url here, but @Client needs an non empty url parameter
   @Client(url) RxHttpClient httpClient
   // other constructor arguments...
)
```

Is there to let Micronaut manage the HttpClient while still using a url from my application.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject the url from your properties using:

```
@Client("${myproperties.url}")
RxWebSocketClient webSocketClient;
```

See: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/httpClient.html

Comment: Works! I totally overlooked that line because it was written in Kotlin .